# How to unmount (close the mount) for sshfs Windows?

Tags: windows, ssh, mount, sshfs, unmount

I've seen lots of posts dexcribing how to mount a remote directory on the local Windows machine using sshfs-win.
But I don't know how to close the mount (unmount), once I'm done?

I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3):

Had the same problem.

We cannot use windows "native" unmount (`net use X: /delete`) because for windows the `sshfs-win` mount is not a network drive but a physical drive (`net use` returns empty set)

[image]

I managed to disconnect this mount by killing `sshfs`, as [it is recommended to do](https://superuser.com/a/816068)

The windows equivalent to the linked answer is :

```
taskkill /f /im sshfs.exe
```

or less brutal:

```
# GET PID
tasklist | findstr /i "sshfs"
# KILL PID
taskkill /PID pid_value
```

This will clear the mount and free the drive letter, so you can mount later on the same disk.

[image]

Comment: 4 years later and some things have changed, sshfs-win later versions now mount as network drive, so `net use X: /delete` works after all.